# Store Button Click in database Django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am developing a Django app, I need to track users click for particular button.

Suppose I have 10 buttons and if logged in user clicks btn1, btn2, and btn5
then I want to store this to my database that user clicked these buttons

Comment: Two ways I think you can go about it are by creating a `ManyToManyField` with a relationship to the buttons you have mentioned, or you can create a `CharField` and append the button to the string. Then, you can iterate over the string to get the information from the buttons.